# Sorting an array that's filled from CoreData

Tags: arrays, swift, core-data, jbchartview

I have a text field in which users can input numerical values and store them to core data as strings. In turn I am retrieving those values and have stored them in an array as ints. What I want to do is sort that array by the order that the user stores the values because I am trying to graph the values to see their trend over time. Right now the values are populating my graph in a totally random manner from all I can tell.

```
var client: Client! = nil
var weights = []

func getWeights() {
        var assessmentWeights: NSSet = client.assessment.valueForKey("weight") as NSSet
        var weightSet: NSSet = assessmentWeights.valueForKey("integerValue") as NSSet
        weights = weightSet.allObjects
        println(weights)
    }
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: Perhaps add a date/time to the stored object and order by that...or a sequence number if you want to save space and don't care about the size of the interval between values.

Comment: I do have an NSDate attribute being stored along side my weight attribute in the object, but I'm not sure how to sort by that date?

Comment: date.compareTo(otherDate);

Answer (score 1):

If you already have a timestamp associated with each weight entry you can either (a) create a `NSFetchRequest` with sort descriptor or you can (b) sort the values you already have in `NSSet`

Since I do not see much code to go with, here's an example of option (b):

```
var weights = [Int]();
if let entries = client.assessment.allObjects as? [Assessment] {
    let sorted = entries.sorted {
        return $0.timestamp.compare($1.timestamp) == .OrderedAscending
    }
    for assessment in sorted {
        if let intValue = assessment.weight.toInt() {
            weights.append(intValue)
        }
    }
}

return weights
```

Having said this, the best option, in my opinion, is to store weight value as a numeric value and use `NSFetchRequest` (result type `.DictionaryResultType`) with sort descriptor on timestamp to get the values you want.

Comment: I'm getting that NSArray does not have a member named 'sort'

Comment: does `client.assessment` has an attribute `weights` which is of type `NSSet?`?  It's a bit challenging to provide the answer without such little information.

Comment: Client has an NSSet of Assessment, and weight is an attribute of the Assessment Entity.

Comment: OK.  What about weight?  What is the type?

Comment: Weight is stored by core data as a string, then, from my understanding (somebody else helped me with this) the int value is being retrieved into my weights array.

Comment: The problem is that I need ints and not strings. I've stored the data as strings in CoreData because strings just seem to be easier to work with in CoreData, but when I pass weights to my JBChart I need it to be an array of ints. Is there a way I could sort the strings and then get their integer value and still keep the sort order when I populate the array with ints?

Comment: Also, in attempting this I got an error. 'Array<Assessment>' does not have a member named 'valueForKey' on the line 'weights = sorted.valueForKey("weight") as! [String]

Comment: Ah... Sorry about that.  Only `NSArray` has `valueForKey`.  Hmmm...  You can always loop through the `sorted` and create an array.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73795/discussion-between-skim-and-leighton).